# Client Server in java

Tags: java, client-server

I'm buliding a client-server application in java (using netbeans).. 
In the client side I have 3 classes and one `Connection` class to handle the sending and receiving data from/to server.. the 3 classes are using the same Connection class, so I thought it will be useful to create one global connection which will be used by the different classes each time they need to send/receive data.

So from C# and c++ I know you can declare a static class, but in Java it's impossible to declare about static class.. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introducing global state is often considered bad practice, but it certainly has its use cases. So, you may want to think about the singleton pattern. [Wikipedia on Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

In java, a simple implementation could look like this (untested code):

```
 public class MyConnectionClass {
   private static final MyConnectionClass SINGLE_INSTANCE = new MyConnectionClass();

   private MyConnectionClass() {}

   public static MyConnectionClass getInstance() {
      return SINGLE_INSTANCE;
   }
 }
```

You would then be able to get the singleton instance whenever you need it using

```
MyConnectionClass.getInstance()
```

Please note, that the class has a private constructor. This makes sure, that you cannot use

```
MyConnectionClass not_singleton_anymore = new MyConnectionClass()
```

It is also possible to use enums, which some consider the best method to implement singletons in Java. 
Example copied from wikipedia:

```
public enum Singleton {
        INSTANCE;
        public void execute (String arg) {
                //... perform operation here ...
        }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought about this implementation also :)

Comment: you're welcome.. i just wasn't so sure about the singelton.. so i asked  this question.. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

The static modifier on a class in Java is implicit: If everything in a class in Java is static, then I suppose one could say it is a static class.

Effectively, even if Java did have a static class modifier, the behavior wouldn't be different from placing static before each element.

Just modify everything with `static` and you'll be alright. If you so choose, add a private constructor so it can't be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

i wll suggest u to make a instance and pass it in constructor of evry other class.. so u wll have the same instance for every class.. it wll be in composition relation

Comment: That's not a very clean solution. It requires an additional argument to each method call dealing with the server/client.